# Is there a way to initialise a new struct variable that does not involve writing a constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, initialization

I think that I vaguely recall that one of the newer c++ standards (maybe its c++11, or maybe 14?...17??) allows you to initialise a struct, whereby you can define a struct and then initialise it without having to write a constructor.

E.g.:

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    int b;
    std::string str;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, test> test_map;
    test_map[0] = test(1, 2, "test1"); // This is the line in question
    // Or it might be more like: test_map[0] = test{1, 2, "test1"};
    return 0;
}
```

I can't recall the name of this special initialisation (or if it even exists)!. So my questions are:

- Is there some new mechanism to achieve this without writing a constructor in the struct "test"?
- If so, what is it called (so I can read more about it).

If this "feature" does not exist then please put me out of my misery!, it could be that my imagination has made this up...

Comment: You are looking for `uniform initialization`.

Comment: @SergeyA not http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization ?

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks! : )) - put as an answer i'll mark it up

Comment: @Slava hm... this looks like the same thing?: https://mbevin.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/uniform-initialization/

Comment: fwiw: just watch out for `vector<int>(5,0)` `!=` `vector<int>{5,0}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "initialize without a constructor" is called *aggregate initialization*, it has always been a part of C++ since day 1. Unfortunately, some might say.

In C++98 you could write:

```
std::map<int, test> test_map;
test temp = { 1, 2, "test1" };
test_map[0] = temp;
```

C++11 added that you can use aggregate initialization in prvalues, so you do not need to declare the intermediate variable (and there are no extra copies):

```
std::map<int, test> test_map;
test_map[0] = { 1, 2, "test1" };

std::map<int, test> m2 = { {0, {1, 2, "test2"}} };    // and this
```

Comment: Just what I am looking for (example and the name of the "thing" : )  .... though it turns out that my MSVC2012 compiler is only partially supporting c++11 so I have to go with C++98 method for now : (

Answer (score 4):

Without a constructor, you can do it like this

```
test_map[0] = test{ 1, 2, "test1" };
```

or simply

```
test_map[0] = { 1, 2, "test1" };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also default initialize:

```
struct test {
    int a{1};
    int b{2};
    std::string str{"test1"};
};
```

Or construct without assignment:

```
std::map<int, test> test_map{ 
    {0, {1, 2, "test1"}}
};
```

Or insert without copy:

```
test_map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(0),
    std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2, "test1"));
```

Comment: That's not quite what I was asking, but interesting non-the-less : ) That first example is also completely new to me. I tried it with my MSVS2012 compiler and it did not like it. Is that a new feature >= c++11?

Comment: Ah ok - thanks, that explains why : ) ... the good news is that we are going to get MSVS2017 v soon, so I will be trying this out :p